# bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/<user>/Projects/iOSProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler, fastlane

I am using the command `bundle exec fastlane <some lane>` in an iOS project and I get this error:

```
[17:19:50]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

➡️  Improve Beta Setup
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/1 [closed] 1 
    04 Feb 2017

➡️  Shell command exited with exit status 2 instead of 0.
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19339 [closed] 5 
    4 weeks ago

➡️  create_keychain throwing Shell command exited with exit status 162 instead of 0
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19374 [closed] 4 
    4 weeks ago

and 93 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=Shell%20command%20exited%20with%20exit%20status%201%20instead%20of%200.&type=Issues&utf8=✓

  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    51: from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
    50: from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    49: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
    48: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
    47: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
    46: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    45: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    44: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
    43: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    42: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    41: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    40: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:484:in `exec'
    39: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    38: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    37: from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    36: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:25:in `<top (required)>'
    35: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane:25:in `load'
    34: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    33: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
    32: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:42:in `start'
    31: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:353:in `run'
    30: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
    29: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
    28: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
    27: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
    26: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
    25: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    24: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    23: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    22: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    21: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    20: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    19: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    18: from Fastfile:644:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    17: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    16: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:146:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    15: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:204:in `try_switch_to_lane'
    14: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    13: from Fastfile:700:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    12: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    11: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:146:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    10: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:204:in `try_switch_to_lane'
     9: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
     8: from Fastfile:729:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
     7: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:214:in `sh'
     6: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:222:in `sh'
     5: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
     4: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:223:in `block in sh'
     3: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:16:in `sh_no_action'
     2: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:80:in `sh_control_output'
     1: from /Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.204.3/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
```

But when I go into `/Users/ebucelik/Projects/AppSolutioniOS/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/fastlane` then I can execute the file. That's really strange.

I tried many things before like updating/reinstalling fastlane, gem, ruby, bundle install/update, deleting Gemfile.lock ...

My ruby version: `ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]`

My fastlane version: `fastlane 2.204.3`

My bundler version: `2.3.5`

My gem version: `3.3.9`

The .zshrc contains the path: `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:$PATH"`

I have simply no idea what to do now because I can not work since I can not run this lane. Hope anyone can help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: Did you happen to figure out what was causing this? I've run into the same issues trying to implement a CircleCI iOS pipeline.

Comment: Hi, I don't remember that much but I think I solved it by deinstalling everything and installing everything new (ruby, fastlane, homebrew...)

Answer (score 0):

If a lane is available with the same name, in my case it fails.

i.e.

```
lane match_nuke
    match_nuke(...)
end
```

It will fail, but if you use:

i.e.

```
lane match_cleanup
    match_nuke(...)
end
```

It will work.

I'm not available to provide any link of documentation so I didn't see it mentioned anywhere.